# JQuery datepicker pre-populated in wrong format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this JavaScript in my JSP file:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#startDate,#endDate').datepicker({
                beforeShow: customRange,
                //defaultDate: "-1w",
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                firstDay: 0,               // first day of the week is Sunday
                numberOfMonths : 2,        // show two months at a time
                changeMonth: true,         // allow changing the month
                changeYear: true           // allow changing the year
        }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    });

    function customRange(input) { 
            var min = new Date()
            ,dateMin = null
            ,dateMax = min
           // ,dayRange = 90 // Set this to the range of days you want to restrict to
            ;

            if (input.id === "endDate") {
                    if ($("#startDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
                            dateMin = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate");
                    }
            }

            return {
                    minDate: dateMin, 
                    maxDate: dateMax
            };     

    }    
</script>
```

When the page loads the startDate and endDate text boxes: "Fri Mar 14 13:54:08 WST 2014" but should be in "dd/mm/yy" format.

On a side note, I also want startDate to have an initial value of 7 days ago.

Any ideas on these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format you're getting is the default `java.util.Date` format, eg:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
// prints: Mon Mar 17 09:41:25 WST 2014
```

Whereas the JavaScript equivalent in a browser console:

```
new Date();
// prints: Mon Mar 17 2014 09:42:04 GMT+0800 (W. Australia Standard Time)
```

So, you'll need to format the Java date via the `formatDate` tag:

```
<fmt:formatDate var="formattedStartDate" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="myForm.startDate" />
<input id="startDate" type="text" value="${formattedStartDate}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign initial value to startDate by using the following code

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: "-7d" });


// getter
var maxDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "-7d" );
```

To set date format using the following code

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
// getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
```

To know more about the datepicker options check this [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it.  I've copy date formatting code before the '$(document).ready(function() {' and after, but neither make any difference.